# Cannot query xxxxx: Must be <Clase> instance

Tags: django, django-urls

Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de un blog con sistema de etiquetado. Cuando pruebo a mostrar información haciendo clic en el enlace de la etiqueta/tag, me lanza este error:

> ValueError at /blog/tag/big-band/"

y como subtítulo del error

> Cannot query "bigband": Must be "Post" instance.

La info más relevante es:

> Request Method:   GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/tag/big-band/ Django Version:    4.1.1
> Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:  Cannot query "bigband":
> Must be "Post" instance. Exception
> Location: /home/luis/DJango3ByExample/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py,
> line 1233, in check_query_object_type Raised
> during:   blog.views.post_list Python
> Executable:   /home/luis/DJango3ByExample/venv/bin/python Python
> Version:  3.9.13 Python Path:  ['/home/luis/DJango3ByExample/mysite',
> '/usr/lib/python39.zip',  '/usr/lib/python3.9',
> '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
> '/home/luis/DJango3ByExample/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Os adjunto los elementos más relevantes:

Paquete que uso --> taggit

models.py:

```
from django.db import models from django.utils import timezone from
django.contrib.auth.models import User from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
            self).get_queryset()\
            .filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
    unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
    choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
    tags = TaggableManager() # manager de las etiquetas

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',args=[self.publish.year,self.publish.month,\
                        self.publish.day, self.slug])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

La view responsable del evento:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404 from
django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage,PageNotAnInteger
from .models import Post,Comment from django.views.generic import
ListView from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm from
django.core.mail import send_mail  from taggit.models import Tag

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                 'blog/post/list.html',
                 {'page': page,
                  'posts': posts,
                  'tag': tag})
```

La url correspondiente:

```
path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
```

Y la plantilla es esta:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %} {% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %} {% block content %}   <h1>My Blog</h1>   {% if tag %}
    <h2>Posts tagged with "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>   {% endif %}   {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="tags">
      Tags:
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <!-- <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a> -->
        <a href="{%url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' tag.slug%}"   >{{ tag.name }} </a>  
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %} -->
      

    </p>
    <p class="date">
      Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>
    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}   {% endfor %}   {% include "../pagination.html" with page=posts %} {% endblock %}
```

Mi visión sobre la cuestión es que el problema está en la url que se genera, pero no alcanzo a encontrar dónde se produce el error.

Answer (score 0):

Hola por que no replanteas esto:

tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

por esto:
tag = Tag.objects.get(slug_tag_slug)
posts = Post.published.filter(tags=tag)

Asimismo el if... para que solo cargues la información que realmente necesitas y no todos los post, entiendo que puede ser más fácil, pero sobrecargar el servidor con información innecesaria, el costo computacional se te va a ir arriba.

Comment: Hola @edsantoshn, he seguido tu consejo.  Pero no me ha dejado, me lanza los problemas siguientes: --> NameError at /blog/tag/bigband/
name 'slug_tag_slug' is not defined ; he corregido dejando --> tag = Tag.objects.get(tag_slug) --> Y me da este error --> ValueError at /blog/tag/bigband/
too many values to unpack (expected 2)  Además, he mirado con un cliente de bdd el contenido de la base de datos y en la tabla Posts, no aparece el campo tags ¿A lo mejor por ahí? Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Tag.objects.get(slug_tag = tag) sorry, no se porque se fue el underscored

Answer (score 0):

he seguido tu idea pero al final he tenido que coger "Pico y pala" y repasar bien el código.  Al final, la línea polémica ha quedado así:

tag = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=tag_slug)

Donde Post es el modelo que va a contener los tags.

Al final la view, ha quedado así:

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
        print(object_list)
        posts = Post.published.filter(tags=tag)

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                 'blog/post/list.html',
                 {'page': page,
                  'posts': posts,
                  'tag': tag})
```

El código de la view post_list ha seguido para adelante; pero me he encontrado el retorno en vacío del campo ampo tag, con lo que la ruta que he definido me da error.

¿Por qué? bueno el parámetro de la view post_list pone tag_slug=None; con lo que la inicializa a 0, lo que tengo que revisar si cambio la condición del if o pongo el código todo seguido hasta llegar al return; tengo que darle una pensada.

Cuando lo consiga, te diré como lo he solucionado.  Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me has hecho pensar con más detenimiento y eso siempre es bueno.

Un saludo

Comment: Recuerda que las respuestas son _para todos_, no para un usuario en particular. Si necesitas hacerle llegar información al autor de la otra respuesta, _debes dejarle un comentario en su respuesta_. A los demás no les llega una notificación cuando alguien más responde a la misma pregunta que respondieron. Ten siempre presente que [es.so] _no es un foro_. Si aún no conseguiste lo que esperabas, borra esta _no-respuesta_ y edita tu pregunta. Si ya lo lograste, edita esta misma respuesta y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).